# Converting String Date to DateTime in python where String format is YYYY-MM-DD Hr-Min-Sec in python

Tags: python, python-datetime

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime_object = datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2005  1:33PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
```

This Date time conversion works, but the input format is a bit different.

```
dateTimeStr="2018-09-28 14:38:41+00:00"
```

or `dateTimeStr="2018-09-28 14:38:41"`

> Looking for some code like

`datetime_object = datetime.strptime('2018-09-28 14:38:41','%YYYY-%MM-%DD %I:%M:%S)`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior Reading the documentation helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it works:

```
datetime_object = datetime.strptime('2018-09-28 14:38:41','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Thanks , could you share a Doc, Where we could see how best to customize '%Y-%m-%d' part.